# Is possible to block the execution until all previous JavaScript listeners completes?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript, I've searched a lot in SO but I have not find any suitable solution yet, not involving chaining. I have two event listeners, registered in this order.

First listener (`module_a.js`) changes a form value:

```
// First listener: handle submit and change recaptcha value
form.addEventListener('submit', async refreshRecaptcha() {
  const { target: form } = e;
  const recaptchaField = form.querySelector('[name="catpcha"]');

  // Simulate long running task
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  recaptchaField.value = token;
});
```

Second listener (`module_b.js`) actually submit the form:

```
// Second listener: POST data to server, with the recaptchaField changed
form.addEventListener('submit', async postData(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Post data
  await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData })
});
```

Second listener should "wait" until the first completes. Or any other async listeners complete.
I cannot "chain" together the two because they are in different modules.

Possible or impossible?

Comment: X/Y problem. Why all those async and await? Move the fetch inside the resolve

Comment: I cannot "chain" together the two because they are in different modules. Every module do just one thing

Comment: The two handlers are run in registration order, but I would not count on the order if they are in different modules. In addition, the whole point of having events is that they are indipendently run. I think you will need to have one attached to one event and the other to something else, probably to the result of the first call. So, as the question is stated, the answer is "impossible".

Comment: "*I cannot "chain" together the two because they are in different modules.*" - so make one module call functions from the other module? Tell us more about those modules and why you think they need to be so independent (and how you still guarantee order of event registrations if they're really independent).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Promises.

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});

myPromise
  .then(handleResolvedA, handleRejectedA)
  .then(handleResolvedB, handleRejectedB)
  .then(handleResolvedC, handleRejectedC);
```

Comment: Cannot chain, different files/modules